# get property of non-object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Please help me solve this problem brother

```
public function pdfview($id){
    $halaman="tindaklayanan";
    $keluhan = keluhan::findOrFail($id);

    $tindakan = DB::table('tindakans')
    ->join('keluhans','keluhans.id','=','tindakans.id_keluhan')
    ->select(DB::raw('id_keluhan, perbaikan_sementara, tanggal, ttd_tanggung1, ttd_tanggung2, revisi_dokumen, 
    target_verifikasi'))->get();

    $analisa = DB::table('analisas')
    ->join('tindakans','tindakans.id','=','analisas.id_tindakan')
    ->join('keluhans','keluhans.id','=','tindakans.id_keluhan')
    ->select(DB::raw('id_tindakan, analisa, tindakan, pic, tanggal_pelaksanaan'))->get();

    return view('laporan.pdfview',compact('keluhan','tindakan','analisa','halaman'));

    //$pdf = PDF::loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
    //return $pdf->stream();
}
```

I Passing $id from keluhan and trying to get tindakan, i think there's nothing wrong but it end with Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: can you show us your error as well?

Comment: can you show us non-object from which you need property ?

Comment: @webpic hello thank you so much for reply me, i try to get 'perbaikan_sementara' from tb analisa

tb analisa has id_keluhan ($id that passed) but how can i access them ?

Comment: @steD like this :

Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\simmb\resources\views\Laporan\pdfview.blade.php)
in a91d0bf3f1f76f8bd127fbba64ab8e20a901068b.php line 107
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\xampp\htdocs\simmb\storage\framework\views/a91d0bf3f1f76f8bd127fbba64ab8e20a901068b.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'keluhan' => object(keluhan), 'tindakan' => array(object(stdClass))

Comment: @ChristianusAndre means you want to get `perbaikan_sementara` from `$tindakan` variable ??

Comment: this is my logic, i passing $id (from keluhan) then tindakan will join tb where keluhan.id = tindakan.id_keluhan then it can get what i want, but why it said no object property

Comment: @webpic i want to get value of perbaikan_sementara from table tindakan where has id like $id keluhan

Comment: can you debug your query and see if there is any error in it? or try to print  `$tindakan` by doing `dd( $tindakan)`

Comment: @webpic i try dd and the result is 

array:1 [▼
  0 => {#327 ▼
    +"id_keluhan": 3
    +"perbaikan_sementara": "Sementara"
    +"tanggal": "2017-03-09 03:06:54"
    +"ttd_tanggung1": "Tulips.jpg"
    +"ttd_tanggung2": "Tulips.jpg"
    +"revisi_dokumen": "Pedoman,Prosedur,Standar"
    +"target_verifikasi": "2017-03-21"
  }
]

Comment: its work and i can get the value when check with dd so nothing wrong but when i tried to access in view it doesn't work well

Comment: @ChristianusAndre try `->get()->toArray();`  and you will get data in array then you can get value by doing  `$tindakan['perbaikan_sementara']`  in views

Comment: @webpic the result is Call to a member function toArray() on array

Comment: i try var_dump($tindakan) and this is the result :

array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#327 (7) { ["id_keluhan"]=> int(3) ["perbaikan_sementara"]=> string(9) "Sementara" ["tanggal"]=> string(19) "2017-03-09 03:06:54" ["ttd_tanggung1"]=> string(10) "Tulips.jpg" ["ttd_tanggung2"]=> string(10) "Tulips.jpg" ["revisi_dokumen"]=> string(24) "Pedoman,Prosedur,Standar" ["target_verifikasi"]=> string(10) "2017-03-21" } }

Comment: @ChristianusAndre can you tell me with only `->get();` how you are accessing in views.

Comment: <td height="20px" rowspan="2" colspan="2"><?php echo $tindakan->perbaikan_sementara ?></td>

Comment: with the same way i call for $keluhan and its work so i confused why it's not work for $tindakan

Comment: wtf error, i can get analisa but can't get tindakan T_T